# How to detect a user login using Java Service Wrapper

Tags: java, windows-services, java-service-wrapper

I have created a Java application and used [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) method 3 that implements the [WrapperListener](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate-listener.html) to convert it to a Windows Service.

The [WrapperManager](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/jdoc/index.html) can be used to identify various events that get raised and caught in the wrapper listener controlEvent function, this includes a user logging off, however doesn't have a user login event.

Is there a way I can detect a user logging in to the system and perform some kind of action in my Java application?
If not, is there a way to detect a spike in CPU usage that I can use to make an assumption of a user logging in?
This is required because my application needs to perform some action when a user logs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no logon control code for user logons within the Service Control Manager. Additionally Java Service Wrapper makes use of common control signals. It would not make much sense to have a CTRL_LOGON_EVENT when working with event handling: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242.aspx

You might need to consider looking around in the Windows Event Log for event id 4648 under Security and programming an implementation of event subscription but it will require an understanding of Windows APIs and the usage of the Java Native Access library:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385771.aspx

The workaround above is not ideal but it's a possible route.

A bit more information about the service you're working on would really help.

**EDIT:**

On user login, this program should run as the user, (refer at bottom for the command):

**LoginServiceDefer.java**

```
import org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager;

public class LoginServiceDefer {
    public static String svc = "loginservice";
    public static int ctrl   = 155;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Sending user control code.");
        try {
            WrapperManager.sendServiceControlCode(svc, ctrl);
            WrapperManager.stop(0);
        } catch (Exception re) {
            System.err.println("System error. Unable to send control code to service, " + svc + ", with control code, " + ctrl + ".");
            re.printStackTrace();
            WrapperManager.stop(1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the listener that will be used in your service. It runs as SYSTEM:

**LoginListener.java**

```
import org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.event.WrapperEvent;
import org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.event.WrapperEventListener;
import org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.event.WrapperServiceControlEvent;


public class LoginListener implements WrapperEventListener
{
    public LoginListener() { }

    public void fired( WrapperEvent event ) {
        if (event instanceof WrapperServiceControlEvent) {
            WrapperServiceControlEvent scEvent = (WrapperServiceControlEvent) event;
            switch (scEvent.getServiceControlCode()) {
                case 155:
                    // LoginServiceDefer has sent a control code.
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Add this line before WrapperManager.start()**

```
WrapperManager.addWrapperEventListener(new LoginListener(), WrapperEventListener.EVENT_FLAG_SERVICE);
```

**Add these two lines to your wrapper.conf**

```
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.security.manager
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.security.policy=java.policy
```

**Create a new file called java.policy.**

Place it in the folder where Wrapper.exe is located (should be wrapper-windows/bin/wrapper.exe).

```
// NOTE: There are ways of limiting the permissions for the notifier using the the library.
grant codeBase "file:../lib/wrapper.jar" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

// Change *my_login_notifier.jar* to whatever LoginServiceDefer.java is as a jar.
grant codeBase "file:./*my_login_notifier.jar*" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Run this command on user login, making sure to cd to the path or edit the java.policy file:

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=java.policy -jar *my_login_notifier.jar*.jar
```

Comment: I have had a look at how it is usually achieved in C# - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5353269/3948757, and assumed there must be some way this can be achieved using the JSW. The service I am working on is a 'agent' that runs tasks given to it by the 'master' on another machine. The agent requires to detect when a user logs onto the machine so it can inform the master and switch the tasks to another agent.

Comment: You're right, I'm close to a possible solution. There's an extended service control code called SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE. Java Service Wrapper doesn't implement straight out of the box but there is a way. Refer to this, http://java-service-wrapper.996253.n3.nabble.com/Stopping-Service-before-Standby-td2726.html

Comment: Does it matter if there is no information about the user? Since Vista, Interactive Services Detection has meant that it is incredibly difficult to get information about the current user. I've managed to find a compromise to this problem. A simple java app that runs in userland and sends a custom control signal to the service which operates outside. The app starts on user login while the service runs at SYSTEM level. The API, getInteractiveUser() is broken so that can't be used for getting user information. Just say and I'll edit my answer to include the code (it's a bit lengthy).

Comment: No it doesn't matter about user information, the only concern of this service is it knows when a user logs on/ off the system. In which case your java service app that sends signals on user login sounds like it might work. Does it matter if you don't actually know the username of the person logging on? I cant remember if you can just set to service to start on generic user login. Also would this method allow me to avoid using the WrapperListener?

Comment: also have you ever looked at JavaExe(http://devwizard.free.fr/html/en/JavaExe.html)? I've just had a look and it appears to allow you to respond to session changes and also runs on windows 64 bit for free whereas you need a paid license for JavaServiceWrapper.

Comment: No but if it does the job then go for it! http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-interactive.html Interactive mode is needed for anything related to fetching data on users from the service. It's a limitation that Microsoft put in place for security and It's likely JavaExe will have some issues as well.

Comment: I have tried to implement the above, however when I run the service application it produces the following stack trace: http://pastebin.com/vbaTDSLH, any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, it was just some configuration issues. You sir, are a legend!

Answer (score 0):

there is another solution called [JavaExe](http://devwizard.free.fr/JavaExe.html). With this tool you can receive some System events into your Java application, like User Connect or Disconnect, ...